# Prevent using this.state within a this.setState (react/no-access-state-in-setstate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

For this piece of code, `!this.state.dark` I am getting an ESlint (airbnb config) error:

```
Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state.
```

I tried refactoring the code using following the [ESlint documentation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md). But I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

```
toggleDark = () => {
  const dark = !this.state.dark
  localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(dark))
  this.setState({ dark })
}
```

Comment: `this.setState(({ dark }) => ({ dark: !dark }))`; see https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: This fixes the ESlint error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for pointing me to appropriate documentation.

It turns out that state updates may be asynchronous. React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. In the came of my code, I only have one value that was being updated. But, it's still a good idea to use a second form of setState that accepts a function rather then an object.

```
toggleDark = () => {
  const dark = !this.state.dark
  localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(dark))

  this.setState(({ dark }) => ({ dark: !dark }))
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to call `setItem` inside your `setState` call back.

Comment: Interesting approach. How would the work? Something like this `this.setState(({ dark, setIteam }) => ({ dark: !dark }))`?

Comment: `this.setState(({ dark }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(!dark));
    return { dark: !dark };
});`