# Accessing context values outside of Context.Consumer

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the value of `ThemeContext.Consumer` in my styled components. I'm using Gatsby to implement dark mode.

This is the `ThemeContext.Consumer` file:

```
import React from 'react'

const defaultState = {
  dark: false,
  toggleDark: () => {},
}
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(defaultState)
// Getting dark mode information from OS!
// You need macOS Mojave + Safari Technology Preview Release 68 to test this currently.
const supportsDarkMode = () =>
  window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches === true
class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dark: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Getting dark mode value from localStorage!
    const lsDark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark'))
    if (lsDark) {
      this.setState({ dark: lsDark })
    } else if (supportsDarkMode()) {
      this.setState({ dark: true })
    }
  }

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005886/eslint-prevent-using-this-state-within-a-this-setstate-react-no-access-state-i?stw=2
  toggleDark = () => {
    const dark = !this.state.dark
    localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(dark))
    this.setState(({ dark }) => ({ dark: !dark }))
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { dark } = this.state
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider
        value={{
          dark,
          toggleDark: this.toggleDark,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
export default ThemeContext
export { ThemeProvider }
```

This is my `Header.js file`:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext'

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const currentTheme = this.props.theme

    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => (
          <HeaderWrapper>
            <span
              role="presentation"
              className="dark-switcher"
              onClick={theme.toggleDark}
            >
              {theme.dark ? <span>☀</span> : <span>☾</span>}
            </span>
          </HeaderWrapper>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

export default Header

const HeaderWrapper = styled.div`
  background: ${() => (theme.dark ? '#C6D0EB' : '#205284')};
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--accents-2);
`
```

I added  `const currentTheme = this.props.theme` to be able to use the value globally. With expectation of being able to use it inside my styled component.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: What's your actual issue? I guess it's the background color not changing? If so you should write it in your question. Also, your `HeaderWrapper` does not have access to `theme`. Pass it explicitly as a prop if need be. And maybe put all of this in a CodeSandBox.io so we can easily check and help :)

Comment: Could you show where exactly `ThemeProvider` is being used?

Comment: Here's the link to CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/laurosilvacom/laurosilvacom. I'm trying to access `theme.dark` from inside my styled components. Instead of adding another class (as you can see from the Codesandbox repo). How can I pass the 'theme' explicitly as a prop? cc: @PowellYe @antoine129

Comment: Thanks Lauro, I believe I know the solution, will compose an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `contextType` property. It works as following:

1) Assign a context object to it;
2) Access provided values on `this.context`.

```
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext'

class Header extends React.Component {
  // as a public class field
  static contextType = ThemeContext

  render() {
    const { toggleDark, dark } = this.context

    return (
      <HeaderWrapper>
        <span
          role="presentation"
          className="dark-switcher"
          onClick={toggleDark}
        >
          {dark ? <span>☀</span> : <span>☾</span>}
        </span>
      </HeaderWrapper>
    )
  }
}

// or as a property
Header.contextType = ThemeContext
```

I noticed you are using a React version which includes support for hooks - if you like, `useContext` hook provides an alternative way to tap into context values.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was trying to implement. Thanks for the help Powell. :D